# Split a line into columns with some of the columns right-justified?

Tags: text-processing, table

Is there an easy way to split comma-delimited lines of text into columns with some of the columns right-justified?

As a bonus, it would be nice to format numbers, but this probably isn't too hard with sed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html) and the `%42s` printf format comes to mind. Here's a simple script to get you started. Setting `width[i]` to a positive value in the `BEGIN` clause makes that column have the given width, left-aligned. If `width[i]` is negative, then column `i` is right-aligned and has the width `-width[i]`. This script doesn't handle wide fields intelligently, all subsequent columns are just shifted right on that line.

```
awk -F, -vOFS= '
BEGIN {width[1]=-10; width[2]=8;}
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {$i = sprintf("%*s", width[i], $i)}
  print }'
```

If you have numeric fields, you can use other [printf formats](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap05.html).

If you have the BSD utility [`column`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=column&sektion=1) (Debian ships it, I don't know about other Linux distributions), you can easily format things in columns with `column -t -s ,`. The nice thing about `column` is that it determines the column width automatically. However, it doesn't do right-hand formatting; while you can get it with some post-processing, I don't know if the complexity is worth it.

You could do everything in Perl. Its [format](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) facility may help.

A more powerful approach to table formatting with common unix tools is [`tbl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tbl), which is the part of *roff (the man page formatter) that handles tables. But that's also more complex because you need to convert the input to roff.

Yet another possible tool is the text mode browser [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/), which is good at table rendering. Here, you'd have to convert the input to HTML.

Comment: Thanks +1, do you know why using printf, rather than sprintf, causes problems with printing the next line on the same line (if I have 4 fields, it prints those fields and then the next line right after that before the line break).

Answer (score 5):

Ended up figuring this out myself. Instead of `column`, use `awk` to produce columns. For example, if foo.txt has lines of the form "bar,36,17.34566", you could do something like

```
cat foo.txt | awk -F, '{printf "%-20s %20d %20.2f\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

to produce columns of width 20, with the first column left-justified, the other two columns right-justified, and the last column with two decimal places of precision.

Answer (score 0):

My pipeline:

```
| nl -nrz\
| rev\
| column -t\
| rev\
| cut -d' ' -f2-
```

1. add fixed width prefix column
2. reverse characters in the string
3. columns left-aligned
4. reverse characters in the string
5. remove the column added in #1